# Pod installation error || Ruby version mismatch || brew error || React native || Mac M1

Tags: react-native

I am using Mac M1. My React native project has been built using Typescript, Firebase. When I try running pod install inside ios folder, I am getting this below error.

```
 `require': dlopen(/Users/kalidass/.rvm/rubies/ruby-
2.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/stringio-3.0.5/lib/stringio.bundle, 0x0009): tried: 
'/Users/kalidass/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/stringio-
3.0.5/lib/stringio.bundle' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 
(x86_64), need (arm64e))) - /Users/kalidass/.rvm/rubies/ruby-
2.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/stringio-3.0.5/lib/stringio.bundle (LoadError)
```

Later I have tried creating a blank React native project, I have noticed the below error.

```
churby: Comman not found

✖ Installing Bundler


error zsh:1: command not found: chruby
WARN: Unresolved or ambiguous specs during   
Gem::Specification.reset:
  ipaddr (>= 0)
  Available/installed versions of this gem:
  - 1.2.2
WARN: Clearing out unresolved specs. Try 'gem cleanup <gem>'
Please report a bug if this causes problems.


error Error: Looks like your iOS environment is not properly     
set. Please go to 
https://reactnative.dev/docs/next/environment-setup and follow 
the React Native CLI QuickStart guide for macOS and iOS.
```

Tried almost whatever possible commands.

```
Opened my terminal using Rosetta
Followed the commands to install pods for M1 chip
```

No luck. Any help is appreciated.

```
node - 16.16.0
npm - 8.11.0
java - 11.0.5
react-native - 8.0.5
ruby - 2.7.4
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, on Apple silicon there is a Ruby issue and I do not know why.

I use [RVM](https://rvm.io/) for handling Ruby issues. I strongly suggest you to use RVM instead of other tools.

You can use `rvm use 2.7.4` and it probably will fix your pod install problem

Answer (score 1):

I had a lot of different issues trying to install ruby on a Mac M1 but now I'm okay with chruby + ruby-install.

Take a look to this guide:
https://www.moncefbelyamani.com/how-to-install-xcode-homebrew-git-rvm-ruby-on-mac/

For Mac M1 care about the good command to install ruby 2.7.4.
It should be: ruby-install 2.7.4 --enable-shared
Also don't run your terminal under Rosetta

Now next time you will upgrade RN, you will just have to refer to the version of the .ruby-version file to install it with ruby-install then check it with ruby --version in your project folder. And all will be okay :)

Comment: Here is my ruby version after few changes
ruby 2.7.4p191 (2021-07-07 revision a21a3b7d23) [arm64-darwin21]

But still when I open my project in terminal, it says Required ruby-2.7.4 is not installed.

Comment: Should I add any path for this Ruby like how we do in windows environmental variable

Comment: I am using 2.7.4 only. Still im not able to reproduce it. => ruby 2.7.4p191 (2021-07-07 revision a21a3b7d23) [arm64-darwin21]

Comment: So to resume: if you execute "ruby-version" from your project directory in your terminal, it return "2.7.4p191 (2021-07-07 revision a21a3b7d23) [arm64-darwin21]". But when you execute pod install from yourdirectory/ios, it return "ruby-2.7.4 is not installed" ?

Comment: When terminal opened, no error on ruby. But when I open my priject root, it throws an error saying, Required ruby-2.7.4 is not installed

Comment: I guess you have some conflicts with some others ruby installations. You can try to check "which ruby"